Creating a column with transitions and time between the transitions in multistate data in R
I have a data frame which contains several date columns for four states A, B, C and D (in no particular order). The states are diagnosis of health conditions. One of the dates is the start date which is when a patient starts to be followed up. A patient can develop any of the conditions first and then followed by another condition etc. I would like to create a column with a label of the transition for each patient ID and another column with time between states for each transition.
I.e. if the starting data is:
data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
              start_date = as.Date(c("2008-02-04","2011-12-04","2002-04-08","1998-03-04","1996-02-02","2010-08-05")),
              StateA = as.Date(c("2011-02-01","2020-09-01",NA,"2010-06-01",NA,"2015-02-02")),
              StateB = as.Date(c("2010-02-01","2018-09-01","2012-03-01",NA,NA,NA)), 
              StateC = as.Date(c("2010-04-01",NA,"2012-06-01","2003-05-01","2000-02-01",NA)),
              StateD=as.Date(c("2011-05-01",NA,"2019-09-10","2014-03-05",NA,"2015-02-08"))
              )


   ID start_date     StateA     StateB     StateC     StateD
1  1 2008-02-04 2011-02-01 2010-02-01 2010-04-01 2011-05-01
2  2 2011-12-04 2020-09-01 2018-09-01       <NA>       <NA>
3  3 2002-04-08       <NA> 2012-03-01 2012-06-01 2019-09-10
4  4 1998-03-04 2010-06-01       <NA> 2003-05-01 2014-03-05
5  5 1996-02-02       <NA>       <NA> 2000-02-01       <NA>
6  6 2010-08-05 2015-02-02       <NA>       <NA> 2015-02-08

The end result should be;

   ID      State       Date Time         Transition
1   1 start_date 2008-02-04    0               <NA>
2   1     StateB 2010-02-01  728     none to StateB
3   1     StateC 2010-04-01   59   StateB to StateC
4   1     StateA 2011-02-01  306  StateBC to StateA
5   1     StateD 2011-05-01   89 StateBCA to StateD
6   2 start_date 2011-12-04    0               <NA>
7   2     StateB 2018-09-01 2463     none to StateB
8   2     StateA 2020-09-01  731   StateB to StateA
9   3 start_date 2002-04-08    0               <NA>
10  3     StateB 2012-03-01 3615     none to StateB
11  3     StateC 2012-06-01   92   StateB to StateC
12  3     StateD 2019-09-10 2657  StateBC to StateD
13  4 start_date 1998-03-04    0               <NA>
14  4     StateC 2003-05-01 1884     none to StateC
15  4     StateA 2010-06-01 2588   StateC to StateA
16  4     StateD 2014-03-05 1373  StateCA to StateD
17  5 start_date 1996-02-02    0               <NA>
18  5     StateC 2000-02-01 1460     none to StateC
19  6 start_date 2010-08-05    0               <NA>
20  6     StateA 2015-02-02 1642     none to StateA
21  6     StateD 2015-02-08    6   StateA to StateD



You can use the lag() function to calculate time between transitions, and the accumulate() function to keep track of previous transitions.
The first steps I do are to format the data better, but you might change these up if your actual data looks different:
First, change the data to long format 
Remove NA's 
Order data by time 
Extract the state 
Then we can get into calculating what you want
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(start_date, contains('state'))) %>% 
  drop_na %>% 
  arrange(ID, value) %>% 
  mutate(state = str_sub(name, -1, -1), 
         state = ifelse(state %in% c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), state, 'none')) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Time = as.numeric(value - lag(value)), Time = replace_na(Time, 0)) %>%
  mutate(Transition = accumulate(state, ~ paste(.x, .y, sep=' -> '))) %>% 
  select(-state) %>% 
  ungroup

# Output:
# A tibble: 21 x 5
      ID name       value       Time Transition              
   <dbl> <chr>      <date>     <dbl> <chr>                   
 1     1 start_date 2008-02-04     0 none                    
 2     1 StateB     2010-02-01   728 none -> B               
 3     1 StateC     2010-04-01    59 none -> B -> C          
 4     1 StateA     2011-02-01   306 none -> B -> C -> A     
 5     1 StateD     2011-05-01    89 none -> B -> C -> A -> D
 6     2 start_date 2011-12-04     0 none                    
 7     2 StateB     2018-09-01  2463 none -> B               
 8     2 StateA     2020-09-01   731 none -> B -> A          
 9     3 start_date 2002-04-08     0 none                    
10     3 StateB     2012-03-01  3615 none -> B 

I don't know how much formatting matters to you, but for the Transition column, you could get your format above by adding on a few lines of string manipulation

Nice answer, but you are taking a couple of extra steps df1 %>% rename("none" = "start_date") %>% pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = "Date", names_to = "State") %>% drop_na() %>% arrange(ID, Date) %>% mutate(Time = as.numeric(Date - lag(Date, default = Date[1])), Transition = ifelse(State == "none", State, paste(lag(State, default = "none"), State, sep = " to ")), .by = ID)

thanks all, this gives me a solution. Is it possible however to have for example for patient ID 1 , StateC to State A to be labeled as StateBStateC to State A as the patient already has StateB? Same for patient ID 4 who has the transition StateCStateA to StateD. Huge thanks.

Yes, using the code M-- left in the comment, we can modify with the accumulate output: data %>% rename("none" = "start_date") %>% pivot_longer(-ID, values_to = "Date", names_to = "State") %>% drop_na() %>% arrange(ID, Date) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Time =  as.numeric(Date - lag(Date, default = Date[1]))) %>% mutate(Transition = accumulate(State, ~ paste(.x, .y, sep='')),Transition = ifelse(row_number() > 1, paste(lag(Transition), 'to', State), NA) ,Transition = ifelse(row_number() != 2, str_remove_all(Transition, 'none'), Transition)) 
